# Trying to submit new records to an access file [.mdb] through VB forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Just a school student working on their project. Tried researching but had no luck, hope you can help.
What I currently have coded for the form I wish to make inputs with is below.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmPlayerInput

    Dim Provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHome.Click
        frmHome.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "Z:\Desktop\players.mdb"
        connString = Provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into Items ([FirstName].[Surname].[TopNumber]) Values (?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("FirstName", CType(txtFirstName.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Surname", CType(txtSurname.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("TopNumber", CType(txtTopNumber.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            txtFirstName.Clear()
            txtSurname.Clear()
            txtTopNumber.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click, btnHome.Click
        txtFirstName.Clear()
        txtSurname.Clear()
        txtTopNumber.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  You've given a cursory explanation of what you're trying to achieve and you've provided the relevant code, but you have explained what the expected and actual behaviour of the code are and how they differ.  If there's an exception thrown then you need to provide details of that.

Comment: That said, your SQL code looks immediately suspicious. You have separated your column names with dots when it should be commas. Dots are used to separate parts of the same name, e.g. `Database.Schema.Table.Column`, much as they are in VB.

Comment: By the way, what's the point of using `CType` to convert the `Text` properties to type `String` when they already are type `String`?

Comment: I would also suggest that the way you appear to be hiding and showing forms is a bad idea.  Most likely, that player input form should just be displayed as a modal dialogue over the home form.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've based my code off any tutorials online I could find. This is my first time working with VB. My main goal right now is to be able create a record in my access table using the text in the texts boxes.

Comment: the error message: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is open.'

Comment: and the other error that opens in the form is: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Answer (score 0):

> the error message: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Not allowed to
>   change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state
>   is open.'

This happens because you are opening your connection and then not closing it if an exception is thrown.  This is an example of why you should be creating, using and destroying such objects locally.  The most proper way to use a connection object is like this:

```
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    'Use connection here.
End Using
```

That will create a new connection object each time, which is the preferred option.  It is a lightweight object, with the actual database connection at a lower level.  The `Using` block also guarantees that the connection will be closed, even if an unhandled exception is thrown within the block.

> and the other error that opens in the form is: Number of query values
>   and destination fields are not the same

This happens because, as I said, you're using dots where you should be using commas.  `[FirstName].[Surname].[TopNumber]` is being interpreted as one column with a qualifying table and schema rather than three columns.